# MATLAB sendmail configuration for a SMTP server

Tags: matlab, email, smtp

We were using an internal SMTP server and Matlab's `sendmail` function worked well. However, our SMTP server has changed and instead of `smtp.companyname.com`, we now have an ip address, say `10.23.154.2`.

The new server doesn't require authentication and also no SSL connection. Still, we are not able to send emails

Version - R2013a,

```
setpref('Internet','E_mail','XYZ')

Old Config: setpref('Internet','SMTP_Server','smtp.xxx.com'),     

New Config: setpref('Internet','SMTP_Server','10.23.154.2'),
```

As per IT team, telnet worked on the server and SMTP worked fine with IronPorts. Please comment.

Comment: That looks like it should work on the Matlab side. Can you send mail from other clients?

Comment: Yes. We just sent an email using telnet and it worked.  Matlab is still not able to send emails.  There should be no login/privilege issues as telnet session from the same machine works fine.